# Label tokenizer not working, loss and accuracy cannot be calculated

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, tokenize

I am using Keras Tensorflow for NLP, I am currently working on the imdb reviews dataset. I would like to make use of the hub.KerasLayer. I want to pass the actual x and y values directly. So the sentences as x and the labels as y in my model.fit statement. My code:

```
import csv
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

imdb, info = tfds.load("imdb_reviews", with_info=True, as_supervised=True)

imdb_train=imdb['train']
imdb_test=imdb['test']

training_sentences=[]
training_labels=[]

test_sentences=[]
test_labels=[]

for a,b in imdb_train:
  training_sentences.append(a.numpy().decode("utf8"))
  training_labels.append(b.numpy())

for a,b in imdb_test:
  test_sentences.append(a.numpy().decode("utf8"))
  test_labels.append(b.numpy())

model = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model, output_shape=[20], input_shape=[], 
                           dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),optimizer='adam', metrics=[tf.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(threshold=0.0, name='accuracy')])
```

Trying

```
history = model.fit(x=training_sentences,
                      y=training_labels,
                      validation_data=(test_sentences, test_labels),
                      epochs=2)
```

doesn't work, because training_labels is not in the correct shape/format. My approach now is to make use of applying the tokenizer again, because I then get the result (from texts_to_sequences) in the correct format/shape. For this I have to first transform it into yes/no (or a/b whatever) string.

```
training_labels_test=[]
for i in training_labels:
   if i==0: training_labels_test.append("no")
   if i==1: training_labels_test.append("yes")
  
testtokenizer=Tokenizer()
testtokenizer.fit_on_texts(training_labels_test)
test_labels_pad=testtokenizer.texts_to_sequences(training_labels_test)

val_labels_test=[]
for i in test_labels:
   if i==0: val_labels_test.append("no")
   if i==1: val_labels_test.append("yes")

testtokenizer.fit_on_texts(val_labels_test)
val_labels_pad=testtokenizer.texts_to_sequences(val_labels_test)
```

Because I now have 1 and 2 as labels, I need to update my model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I then try to fit it:

```
history = model.fit(x=training_sentences,
                      y=test_labels_pad,
                      validation_data=(test_sentences, val_labels_pad),
                      epochs=2)
```

Problem is that loss is nan and accuracy is not calculated correctly.

[image: examp]

Where is the mistake?

Please not that my question is really about this specific way and why this tokenizer is not working. I am aware that there are other possibilities which would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be two-fold.

First, binary targets should always be `[0, 1]` and not `[1, 2]`. So, I subtracted one from your targets. `Tokenizer()` isn't made to encode labels, you should use `tfds.features.ClassLabel()` for that. For now, I just subtracted 1 in the `fit()` call.

```
history = model.fit(x=training_sentences,
                      y=list(map(lambda x: x[0] - 1, test_labels_pad)),
                      validation_data=(test_sentences, 
                                       list(map(lambda x: x[0] - 1, val_labels_pad))),
                      epochs=1)
```

Second, your input layer returned only `nan` for some reason. On the [page](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf2_text_classification) of the pre-trained model, they say that:

> `google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim-with-oov/1` - same as `google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1`, but with 2.5% vocabulary converted to OOV buckets. **This can help if vocabulary of the task and vocabulary of the model don't fully overlap**.

And so you should use the second one since your dataset doesn't fully overlap with the data it was trained on. Then, your model will start learning.

```
model = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim-with-oov/1"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model, output_shape=[20], input_shape=[],
                           dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)
```

Full running code:

```
import csv
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

imdb, info = tfds.load("imdb_reviews", with_info=True, as_supervised=True)

imdb_train=imdb['train']
imdb_test=imdb['test']

training_sentences=[]
training_labels=[]

test_sentences=[]
test_labels=[]

for a,b in imdb_train:
  training_sentences.append(a.numpy().decode("utf8"))
  training_labels.append(b.numpy())

for a,b in imdb_test:
  test_sentences.append(a.numpy().decode("utf8"))
  test_labels.append(b.numpy())

training_labels_test = []
for i in training_labels:
    if i == 0: training_labels_test.append("no")
    if i == 1: training_labels_test.append("yes")

testtokenizer = Tokenizer()
testtokenizer.fit_on_texts(training_labels_test)
test_labels_pad = testtokenizer.texts_to_sequences(training_labels_test)

val_labels_test = []
for i in test_labels:
    if i == 0: val_labels_test.append("no")
    if i == 1: val_labels_test.append("yes")

testtokenizer.fit_on_texts(val_labels_test)
val_labels_pad = testtokenizer.texts_to_sequences(val_labels_test)

model = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim-with-oov/1"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(model, output_shape=[20], input_shape=[],
                           dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])

history = model.fit(x=training_sentences,
                      y=list(map(lambda x: x[0] - 1, test_labels_pad)),
                      validation_data=(test_sentences, 
                      list(map(lambda x: x[0] - 1, val_labels_pad))),
                      epochs=1)

model.predict(training_sentences)
```

```
24896/25000 [==================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5482 - sparse_cat_acc: 0.7312
```

```
array([[-0.94201976, -1.3173063 ],
       [-3.7894788 , -3.0269182 ],
       [-3.0404441 , -3.4826043 ],
       ...,
       [-2.8379505 , -1.2451388 ],
       [-0.7685702 , -3.1836908 ],
       [-1.7252465 , -3.8163807 ]], dtype=float32)
```

Look what happens if you have 3 categories, and use `[1, 2, 3]` instead of `[0, 1, 2]`:

```
y_true = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
y_pred = tf.constant([[0.05, 0.95, 0], [0.1, 0.8, 0.1], [.2, .4, .4]])
scce = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
scce(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
```

```
nan
```

But it works with `[0, 1, 2]`:

```
y_true = tf.constant([0, 1, 2])
y_pred = tf.constant([[0.05, 0.95, 0], [0.1, 0.8, 0.1], [.2, .4, .4]])
scce = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
scce(y_true, y_pred).numpy()
```

```
1.3783889
```

Comment: Thanks and plus 1 for your answer, however why do you then use model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2))? You did substract 1 from the labels, so we have 0 and 1, so it should be 1 unit in the last layer and BinaryCrossentropy in loss and Binary Accuracy in metrics?

Comment: Furthermore: Why can I not do [1] and [2] with SparseCategorical? Here in the official Coursera Tensorflow course they do use the tokenizer on labels: https://github.com/lmoroney/dlaicourse/blob/master/TensorFlow%20In%20Practice/Course%203%20-%20NLP/Course%203%20-%20Week%202%20-%20Exercise%20-%20Answer.ipynb so they have 5 classes (1,2,3,4,5), not only 2 (but they are also missing the 0). So why is this "forbidden" in case of two classes? And I am further confused, because you do use SparseCategorical and 2 units in the last layer.

Comment: `sparse_` for loss functions or metrics means that the **input** is **not** one-hot encoded. it's all explained here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy. for your second question, i must say i'm confused. i'm inclined to say that they made a mistake. look what happens when you put something else than `[0, 1, 2]` in a 3 category loss function (see bottom of my answer)